# Dragons and Others in Game of Thrones (possible spoilers)

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

As the more cunning of you might already know, there is a direct correlation between Dragons and Others in the Game of Thrones saga.

There is a plethora of quotes proving that Dragons are magical beings and with their recent return, magic has also returned to the world.

> For example, that is what the warlocks said when they tried to steal the dragons from Daenerys Targaryen

At the very same time, we witness the 'rise' of Whitewalkers and wights. I think therefore, it is safe to assume, that the Others are magical creatures, drawn by magic.

Adding to the above that dragons seem so hard (if not impossible) to control and that the Others are marching to the South, is it possible that

> the Whitewalker horde is heading to confront the Dragons? And that they maybe want to rest in peace, therefore trying to kill the dragons.

Appreciate any answer, suggestions or legit assumption.

Comment: The White Walkers appear in the prologue of the first book *A Game of Thrones*, long before the dragons were born. Also, Dragons were alive long before that, during the days of old Valyria. Aegon the Conqueror had three dragons himself in Westeros. So it would not make sense that these particular dragons woke the walkers, when there had been so many dragons before them.

Comment: Your assumption is flawed: there doesn't seem to be a *direct* correlation between the Others and the dragons, save that they're both magical creatures. So far their resurgence seems to be unrelated (but of course, it could be shown otherwise in future books).

Comment: @AndresF. So you just said that there might be some connection in the near future. Cause that is my actual question.. I haven't read the books, just following the series.

Comment: @TLP the dragons would have been alive in the eggs of course no gestation (not sure thats the right term) is mentioned so they could be draw to the embryos growing in the eggs.

Comment: @Dreamwalker If that was the case, then why are the Others returning in force just now, after thousands of years?

Comment: The only possible connection currently, aside from the whole 'Ice and Fire' aspect, is that Others are magical creatures. This is important as magic largely disappeared from the world with the Doom of Valyria, and even more so when the last dragons died. But now that Daenery's dragons have been born, it is obvious that magic is returning to the world. But this doesn't explain the fact that the Others first started reappearing at least a year before the birth of the dragons. Or the fact that magic was in wide use for thousands of years after the Long Night.

Comment: @AndresF. So you do you think it's a mere coincidence that Dragons and the Others re-appear in the same time. That's hard to believe for me

Comment: I'm not saying anything except that there is no *direct correlation* shown so far. You're assuming too much. Basically we don't know yet. All we know is that the Others first appeared in the Long Night thousands of years before any mention of dragons, and then reappeared before Daenerys awakened her dragons. Is there any relationship bewteen the two? If so, it's not apparent yet.

Comment: @TLP I agree a wrong assumption is no reason for closing, but here the actual question seems to be unclear/opinion-based. Here it is: "Is it possible the Whitewalker horde is heading to confront the Dragons? And that they maybe want to rest in peace, therefore trying to kill the dragons.". That's more or less the definition of opinion-based and "guessing the future". Who knows? Maybe the Others are racing to confront the dragons, maybe they're racing to a hidden magical meteorite, maybe their attacks are periodical. We're guessing here.

Comment: @AndresF. Well, as with all ASOIAF questions, just because it has not happened yet does not mean someone knows the answer. I could lay out pretty convincing answers about things in ASOIAF that has not been revealed yet, based on clues and foreshadowing, such as the identity of Jon Snow's mother, Brienne's famous ancestor, where Tysha is, who Azor Ahai is, etc.

Comment: @KapelNick: I don't think anyone believes it's a coincidence they're at the same time.  But that doesn't mean they're connected in that particular way.  Magic was suddenly back in the world for some yet-to-be-revealed reason, and that brought back white walkers, dragons, _Gods_, burning glass candles... even "the children" have made a reappearance.  I think they're not connected to each other so much as whatever brought magic back.

Comment: This is essentially asking "Which came first; the chicken (dragons and White Walkers) or the egg (magic)?". It is certain that they *are* connected, in some way or another; but there is certainly too little evidence to determine the direct correlation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The White Walkers appear in the prologue of the first book A Game of Thrones, long before the dragons were born. The same goes for the TV-show, although they were more coy about showing the White Walkers.

Besides that, Dragons were alive long before that, during the days of old [Valyria](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyria). [Aegon the Conqueror](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen) had three dragons himself while conquering Westeros.

So it would not make sense that Daenerys' dragons woke the walkers, when there had been so many dragons before them.

You are however correct in assuming that dragons are deadly enemies of Others. We know that they hate fire, and dragons are living fire.

> *There will come a day after a long summer when the stars bleed and the cold breath of darkness falls heavy on the world. In this dread
>   hour a warrior shall draw from the fire a burning sword. And that
>   sword shall be Lightbringer, the Red Sword of Heroes, and he who
>   clasps it shall be Azor Ahai come again, and the darkness shall flee
>   before him.* ([source](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai))

Comment: You are not quite proving anything with your answer. You are stating one fact and then jumping to conclusion. Unless..

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. I just told you there had been dragons before. Most of them disappeared with the [Doom of Valyria](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doom_of_Valyria), some ~500 years before AGOT. Actually, I just read that Valyria is 5000 years old, which would mean they came to power shortly after the Long Night.

Answer (score 7):

In the known history of Westeros there is only two mass White Walker attacks on humans:

- The first one is shrouded in myth and legend and happened **eight thousand years ago**. An event known as The Long Night. Westerosi legends say that it was the Night's Watch who eventually defeated them, while other cultures say that a hero named Azor Ahai defeated them.
- The second one is occurring right now in the books. With the first recorded instance of aggression happening during **the prologue of the first book.**

Now let's look at the history of dragons in Westeros.

- Dragons are native to Essos, a continent east of Westeros.
- **Five thousand years ago**, they were first trained to be creatures of war by the Valyrians. Valyria was a peninsula in southern Essos.
- **Four hundred years ago**, fleeing the Doom of Valyria the Targaryens (and other Valyrian families) settle in Dragonstone. They bring their dragons with them, introducing the species to Westeros.
- **Three hundred years ago**, the Targaryens start their war of conquest in the Seven Kingdoms utilizing their dragons.
- **One hundred and fifty years ago**, the last of the dragons die. They are now extinct in both Westerors and Essos.
- **At the end of the first book**, Dany's three eggs hatch, reintroducing the dragons to Essos (but not Westeros).

I've bolded the times of major events in the history of White Walkers and dragons, and as you can see there is no apparent connection between the appearance/disappearance of dragons with the appearance/disappearance of White Walkers.

Comment: alright so there is no hard evidence to support my claim regarding the appearance of the two. But still that doesn't ask the question "What happens when those two co-exist in the world?"

Comment: @KapelNick That's why I added my quote. Azor Ahai is reborn to combat the evil, and darkness shall flee before him.

Comment: @kapelnick - We don't know. No such event is recorded in history.

Comment: @Kei: “still that doesn't ask the question "What happens when those two co-exist in the world?"” You never asked that question.